# AWS Lambda : body size is too long with raw file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function that return an image file. When trying to return the raw bytes of a 3MB image, I get the error message : "body size is too long"

However, when encoding the image to base64, the lambda works properly. I don't understand this behavior since the base64 image is bigger than the raw image.

```
Raw image            : 3116012 bytes
Base64 encoded image : 4154684 bytes
```

Why do I get this error ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66971400/aws-lambda-body-size-is-too-large-error-but-body-size-is-under-limit

Comment: Consider serving images directly from S3, via pre-signed URL if it needs to be private.