# Request must be smaller for InvokeFunction

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that works as expected when my input is 2 or 3 words. But if I have 2 or 3 paragraphs, I get an error.

```
# wc t.txt 
# returns 5  320 4867 t.txt
```

There are less than 5 thousand bytes and I get this error from Lambda Function URI

```
{"Message":"Request must be smaller than 6291456 bytes for the InvokeFunction operation"}
```

The text is certainly smaller than 6 million bytes. I do not see any reason why should I get this error.

---

Update:

As per the docs "The maximum size for a Lambda event payload is 256 KB." But the text that I tried is a lot smaller than that.

In order to reproduce my issue, copy paste the URL in browser.

https://cct6oyi3jtfxdgf4dssguux3q0ocqv.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/?

Copy-paste the text next to question mark shown above. You will get the expected results.

```
मग  त्यानेच  सांगितलं  की  गावामध्ये  एक  अपराधी  लोकांना  त्रास  देत  सुटला  आहे  लोकांना  पळवणं  आणि  गायब  करणं  सुरू  झालं  आहे  आणि  अपराधी  इतका  तयारीचा  आहे  की  लोकांना  जाणीवही  नाही  अजून  की  असं  काही  घडलंय    त्याने  मग  आमच्या  दूरच्या  मित्रांच्या  संदर्भात  माहिती  दिली  की  त्यांच्यासोबत  काय  घडलंय  ते  ऐकून  धक्का  बसला  मग  मीच  त्याला  बोललो  की  हे  तू  पोलिसांना  का  सांगितलं  नाही  इथे  का  सांगतोय  त्यावर  तो  म्हणाला    शत्रू  खूपच  खतरनाक  आहे  इतका  की    त्याच्याही  जीवाला  धोका  आहे  त्यामुळे  अगदी  जपून  आणि  सगळी  काळजी  घेऊन  आपल्याला  काम  केलं  पाहिजे  मग  मी  त्याला  विचारलं  की  हे  तुला  कसं  कळालं  तो  म्हणाला  की    एका  बेकरीमध्ये  जाताना  त्याला  एका  व्हॅनमधलं  ओरडणं  ऐकून  शंका  आली  आणि  ज्याला  गायब  केलं  होतं  त्याचा  मित्र  जितेशला  त्या  दिवशी  भेटला  त्यामुळे  त्याला  कळालं  की  असं  काही  होतं  आहे  आणि  मग  त्याने  अजून  पुढचे  तपशील  सांगितले  ते  ऐकताना  भितीही  वाटत  होती  आणि  काळजीही  वाटत  होती    त्यानेच  सांगितलं  की  गावामध्ये  एक  अपराधी  लोकांना  त्रास  देत  सुटला  आहे  लोकांना  पळवणं  आणि  गायब  करणं  सुरू  झालं  आहे  आणि  अपराधी  इतका  तयारीचा  आहे  की  लोकांना  जाणीवही  नाही  अजून  की  असं  काही  घडलंय    त्याने  मग  आमच्या  दूरच्या  मित्रांच्या  संदर्भात  माहिती  दिली  की  त्यांच्यासोबत  काय  घडलंय  ते  ऐकून  धक्का  बसला  मग  मीच  त्याला  बोललो  की  हे  तू  पोलिसांना  का  सांगितलं  नाही  इथे  का  सांगतोय  त्यावर  तो  म्हणाला    शत्रू  खूपच  खतरनाक  आहे  इतका  की    त्याच्याही  जीवाला  धोका  आहे  त्यामुळे  अगदी  जपून  आणि  सगळी  काळजी  घेऊन
```

Now add this line at the end of the text mentioned above.

```
आपल्याला  काम  केलं  पाहिजे  मग  मी  त्याला  विचारलं  की  हे  तुला  कसं  कळालं  तो  म्हणाला  की    एका  बेकरीमध्ये
```

And you will get an error:

```
{"Message":"Request must be smaller than 6291456 bytes for the InvokeFunction operation"}
```

The text is smaller than 256 KB limit.

---

Update 2:

The r.content is empty. But the expected result is:

[{"गावाम": "गावा गमावा वावगा"}]

How do i write post request in python?

```
import requests
myurl = 'https://qcct6oyi3jtfxdgf4dssguux3q0ocqvt.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/?'
r = requests.post(myurl, data='गावाम'.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: How exactly are you invoking the function…?

Comment: In Chrome adding text next to /?

Comment: tried from android APP (kotlin) same issue faced.

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67477259/1505146) answer. Since you don't share any code, I can only guess that your issue is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are invoking the AWS Lambda function from python you can use `boto3` lambda client.

check https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda/client/invoke.html

For example:

```
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='my-function',
    Payload='{}',
    Qualifier='1',
)

print(response)
```

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, during synchronous operation, the request payload limit for the lambda function is 6MB (6291456 bytes), not 256KB. The 256KB limit applies only to asynchronous invocation.

Reference: [Invocation Payload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html#function-configuration-deployment-and-execution)

[image]

Although the API request size was less than 6MB, you received the following message from the lambda function: `Request must be smaller than 6291456 bytes for the InvokeFunction operation`. The error message from the lambda function is wrong and hiding the actual problem.

The actual root cause of this issue is not related to the request payload size but rather to the request URL length. Since you passed a lengthy request URL, the lambda function rejects requests with the `414 URI Too Long` status code.

[image]

Therefore, to avoid this problem, either reduce the request URL length or pass the mentioned value to the lambda function from the request body using the HTTP POST method.

```
curl -d '{"key1":"value1"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://qcct6oyi3jtfxdgf4dssguux3q0ocqvt.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/
```

Comment: How to make a post request using python?

Comment: @shantanuo I recommed requests library

Comment: updated the answer with curl command. wrt python post request, you can refer to [this](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/making-http-requests-in-python) website or post a separate question.

Comment: Curl command returns an empty list []

Comment: The curl command just denotes how to make a post request. To get results from lambda function for POST request, you have to make some code changes on your lambda function. I suspect, your lambda function is designed such way to return response only for query strings, and that needs to be adjusted to return response for POST request with request body as well.

Comment: Can you link to an example that will return response for POST request?